# Multi-level grouping using a CollectionViewSources

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

When databinding a `TreeView`, how would you create multiple levels of grouping for the items displayed?

Imagine you are binding to a Shop class which, among others, has the properties `Region` and `RetailChain`. The desired effect is to have a `TreeView` that displays the shops in the following topology:

```
+ Region: California
|  + Walmart
|    + Walmart Pacific Beach
|    + Walmart Orange County
|    + Walmart San Diego
+ Region: New Jersey
   + Frys
   | + Frys Electronics NJ
   + Walmart
     + Walmart New Jersey
```

The clincher is this: `Region`s aren't related to `Retailer`s, and vice versa, so the `Shop` (the leaf node) is the only common denominator.

Using `CollectionViewSource` only allows for a single level of grouping (despite the fact that the `CollectionView` class has properties that suggest multi-level grouping).

Using the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` only works for top-down topologies, which this scenario doesn't lend itself to.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to my problem turned out to be this:

Add multiple groupings (via PropertyGroupDescriptor) to the CollectionViewSource, then use a ListBox / DataGrid with multiple GroupStyles. The nett effect of this is that the leaf items (in my example, the stores) are grouped at two distinct levels.

Switching which PropertyGroupDescriptor appears first in the CollectionViewSource will change which property is the "root" level in the resulting tree.

Comment: I think I have a scenario similar to yours but I was unable to understand your answer clearly. Could you please help me in finding a solution to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482570/how-to-obtain-multi-level-hierarchy-with-collectionviewsource-to-bind-to-semanti

Comment: Very cool thanks. But code examples are always better than words describing code. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write code that will pre-process the data and create a set of classes for easier binding.