# How to obtain Multi-level hierarchy with CollectionViewSource to bind to Semantic Zoom in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, collectionviewsource, semantic-zoom

I have a Windows 8.1 Application in which I am trying to achieve 3 levels of Hierarchy with CollectionViewSource and then Bind it to my Semantic Zoom

My model class looks as follows

```
class Transaction
{
    string id {get; set;}
    string name {get; set;}
    DateTimeOffset date {get; set;
}
```

Sample value of this model could be as follows

```
[1, Food, 31/08/2014]
[2, Movie, 15/08/2014]
[3, Medicine, 20/07/2014]
[4, GameConsole, 02/07/2014]
[5, MobileBill, 18/06/2014]
[4, Tv, 06/06/2014]
```

I want to display this data in my Semantic Zoom such that

1. My ZoomedOutView is a GridView which displays Months like August, July and June.
2. In my ZoomedInView the data is grouped by the date

To achieve this I have to create these 3 levels in my CollectionViewSource

1. Month
2. Date
3. Individual Transaction

An example data for the above hierarchy is shown below

```
August (Appears in ZoomedOutView only)
    August 31
        Transaction 1
        Transaction 2
    August 15
        Transaction 3
        Transaction 4
    August 1
        Transaction 5
        Transaction 6

July (Appears in ZoomedOutView only)
    July 20
        Transaction 7
        Transaction 8
    July 2
        Transaction 9
        Transaction 10

June (Appears in ZoomedOutView only)
    June 10
        Transaction 11
        Transaction 12
```

My Semantic Zoomed Out View will have

```
August
July
June
```

My Semantic Zoom ZoomedInView should have

```
August 31
    Transaction 1
    Transaction 2
August 15
    Transaction 3
    Transaction 4
August 1
    Transaction 5
    Transaction 6
July 20
    Transaction 7
    Transaction 8
July 2
    Transaction 9
    Transaction 10
June 10
    Transaction 11
    Transaction 12
```

I am trying to group my List into CollectionViewSource as follows

```
List<Transaction> response = GetTransactions();
var TransactionCollectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
TransactionCollectionViewSource.Source = response.ToGroups(x => x, x => x.date.Month);
TransactionCollectionViewSource.IsSourceGrouped = true;
```

I have got groupby month, now how do I group this into days again?
Should I have 2 CollectionViewSource? Or is it possible to achieve this with just one CollectionViewSource. I am confused.

I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455775/how-can-used-semantic-zoom-for-3-level-in-uwp/52464082#52464082

Answer (score 0):

SemanticZoom: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465319.aspx

Try this:

```
private void Zoom_ViewChangeStarted(object sender, SemanticZoomViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsSourceZoomedInView)
    {
        e.DestinationItem.Item = _selectedHubSection;
    }
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Sorry what is _selectedHubSection? Where is it declared/defined?
Also I kindly request you to explain in a wee more detail on how this works.

I need the zoom-in to work properly. For instance, if I click on August in the ZoomedOutView, it should show me Transactions of August in the ZoomedInView and so on.